# Why does set_xticklabels only work as intended after using set_xticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Going through the [Matplotlib bar graph demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-label-demo-py), I found this code produced the following plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, -27)
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, -25)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

p1 = ax.bar(x, menMeans, width, yerr=menStd, label='Men')
p2 = ax.bar(x,womenMeans, width, bottom=menMeans, yerr=womenStd, label='Women')

ax.axhline(0, color='grey', linewidth=0.8)
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
# ax.set_xticks(x)
# ax.set_xticklabels(['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5'])
ax.legend()
```

[image: Barplot 1]

Regardless of whether `ax.set_xticks(x)` is uncommented, I get the above plot.
However, if I uncomment only `ax.set_xticklabels(['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5'])` I get this:

[image: Barplot 2]

I have to uncomment both `ax.set_xticks(x)` and `ax.set_xticklabels(['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5'])` to get the desired plot:

[image: Barplot 3]

Can someone please explain why `ax.set_xticks(x)` seems to only make a difference when I also call `ax.set_xticklabels()`

Thank you

Comment: If you don't explicitly set the xtick positions, internal xtick positions are used. In order to delay as much as possible unnecessary calculations, the internal xtick positions are only really set when drawing (and they can change when e.g. zooming).  Therefore, for `set_xticklabels()` to be reliable, first `set_xticks()` should be called.  Note that your test (especially without providing test data) just is one test case, and the behavior will change depending on many circumstances.

Comment: If you run `ax.get_xticks()` after creating the plot with `ax.set_xticks(x)` commented and uncommented, you can see that in this particular case it does indeed make a difference to the list of ticks while not producing any visible effect on the resulting image.